# Заполнение таблицы предвычисленным количеством бит (вес Хэмминга)

Tags: golang, битовые-операции

Помогите разобраться, что происходит в этом коде. Функция инициализации пакета заполняет таблицу предвычисленным количеством битов в числе i.

```
package main

var pc [256]byte

func init() {
    for i := range pc {
        pc[i] = pc[i/2] + byte(i&1)
    }
}

func main() {

}
```

1. pc[0] = 0
2. pc[i] вычисляется как сумма некоторого предыдущего значения и младшего бита в числе i

Не понятно, что означает `pc[i/2]`. Деление на 2 это то же самое, что битовый сдвиг вправо на единицу. В чем заключается магия?